# What is the run time of this code in Theta notation?

Tags: c++, big-o

I am struggling a bit with run time analysis and wanted to see if got those right.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out if I made any mistakes.

```
void f1(int* arr, int n){

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) ---> time complexity = n
       reverseArray(arr, i);
}

void reverseArray(int* arr, int n){
   int left, right, temp;

   for (left = 0, right = n-1; left <= right; left++, right--){ ---> time complexity = n
       temp = arr[left];
       arr[left] = arr[right];
       arr[right] = temp;
   }
}
```

For f1: T(n) = n * n = **O(n^2)**

```
int f2(int n){
   int i, j, c;
   arr = new int[n];

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n 
       arr[i] = 7;

   c = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n
       for (j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) ---> time complexity = n
           c++;

   delete []arr;
   return c;
}
```

For f2: T(n) = n + n^2 = **O(n^2)**

Comment: " I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out if I made any mistakes." Well, you only gave your answers, with no reasoning. So if you got the wrong answer, there's no way to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Easy way to find out: Test for various values of N, like powers of 10 (1, 10, 100, 1000, ...) where you'll quickly find out the shape of the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time complexity of f1 is correct.
But in f2,

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n
       for (j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) ---> time complexity = n
           c++;
```

the second for loop runs exactly for a[i] number of times for each i, but you have initialised  `arr[i] = 7;` in previous for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n 
       arr[i] = 7;
```

This means the second for loop,

```
for (j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) ---> time complexity = n
           c++;
```

runs for eactly **7 times for each i**, leading to 7*n operations.
 Thus total time complexity of **f2** is, **O(n + 7*n) = O(n)**

Answer (score 0):

```
int f2(int n){
   int i, j, c;
   arr = new int[n];

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n 
       arr[i] = 7;

   c = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ---> time complexity = n
       for (j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) ---> time complexity is 7, i.e O(1).
           c++;

   delete []arr;
   return c;
}
```

For f2: T(n) = O(n) + O(n) * O(1) = O(n).

Any number instead 7 can be used, regardless this constant number the inner loop has time complexity O(1). If 7 was not a constant, but an argument m of the function `int f2(int n, int m)`, then the time complexity would be O(m), and O(n*m) in sum.